# Unique Key as array cloud formation template AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to create a cloud formation template for a dynamo db table I want to create. I want the following fields in the table: guid, uniqueid, service.

how can I make the guid and service a primary key that is an array.

here's what I have

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Parameters": {
    "UsersUniqueIdsTableName": {
      "Description": "Table name to use",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "test-db-user-unique-ids"
    },
    "UniqueIdsReadCapacityUnits": {
      "Description": "Provisioned read throughput",
      "Type": "Number",
      "Default": "1",
      "MinValue": "1",
      "MaxValue": "10000",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be between 1 and 10000"
    },
    "UniqueIdsWriteCapacityUnits": {
      "Description": "Provisioned write throughput",
      "Type": "Number",
      "Default": "1",
      "MinValue": "1",
      "MaxValue": "10000",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be between 1 and 10000"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "marvelUsers": {
      "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
      "Properties": {
        "TableName": {
          "Ref": "UsersUniqueIdsTableName"
        },
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "guid",
            "AttributeType": "S"
          },
          {
            "AttributeName": "service",
            "AttributeType": "S"
          },
          {
            "AttributeName": "uniqueid",
            "AttributeType": "S"
          }
        ],
        "KeySchema": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "guid",
            "KeyType": "HASH"
          }
        ],
        "GlobalSecondaryIndexes": [
          {
            "IndexName": "unique",
            "KeySchema": [
              {
                "AttributeName": "reminder_day",
                "KeyType": "HASH"
              }
            ],
            "Projection": {
              "ProjectionType": "ALL"
            },
            "ProvisionedThroughput": {
              "ReadCapacityUnits": {
                "Ref": "UniqueIdsReadCapacityUnits"
              },
              "WriteCapacityUnits": {
                "Ref": "UniqueIdsWriteCapacityUnits"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
          "ReadCapacityUnits": {
            "Ref": "UniqueIdsReadCapacityUnits"
          },
          "WriteCapacityUnits": {
            "Ref": "UniqueIdsUsersWriteCapacityUnits"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamodb partition or sort key should be scalar data type (I.e. String, Number, Boolean etc). The document data types such as map, list, set cannot be part of key attribute.